# Is there a physical interpretation of the algebraic Bianchi identity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, intuition

The Riemann curvature tensor $R_{ijkl}$ satisfies several algebraic index symmetries:

1. $R_{ijkl} = -R_{jikl} = -R_{ijlk}$
2. $R_{ijkl} = R_{klij}$
3. $R_{i[jkl]} = 0.$

I more or less understand how to interpret the first two identities: the first one says that the Riemann curvature tensor can be interpreted as a linear operator on the space of 2-forms $\Lambda^2(M)$, while the second one says that this linear operator is self-adjoint.

But I don't really know how to think about the third identity, the algebraic Bianchi identity. Does it have any physical intuition?

([This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/463588/) asks the same thing about the second or "geometric" Bianchi identity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the special case of the first Bianchi identity
$$
d{\bf T}^a+ {{\boldsymbol \omega}^a}_b\wedge {\bf T}^b -{{\bf R}^a}_b \wedge {\bf e}^{*a}=0,
$$
that follows by taking the exterior derivative of  the definition of torsion two-form
$$
d{\bf e}^{*a}+ {{\boldsymbol \omega}^a}_b\wedge {\bf e}^{*b}={\bf T}^a,
$$
and using ${\bf R}= d{\boldsymbol \omega}+  {\boldsymbol \omega}\wedge  {\boldsymbol \omega}$.
If the connection is torsion-free ${\bf T}^a=0$ then the first two tems vanish and we have
$$
{{\bf R}^a}_b \wedge {\bf e}^{*a}=0.
$$
In the coordinate basis the last equation reduces to ${R^\lambda}_{[\mu\nu\sigma]}=0$.

The geometry behind all the Bianchi identies is that $d^2=0$

Comment: Does ${\boldsymbol \omega}$ represent the connection form corresponding to some local frame ${\bf e}^*$? I'm not familiar with those concepts - no need to explain them - but I've seen that notation before.

Comment: Yes. If $X= X^c {\bf e}_c= X^\mu \partial_\mu $ is a vector field and ${\bf e}_a$ a vielbein basis, then  $\nabla_X {\bf e}_a = {\bf e}_b {\omega^b}_{ac} X^c= {\bf e}_b {\omega^b}_{a\mu} X^\mu$.  Then ${{\boldsymbol \omega}}^a_b ={ \omega^a}_{b \mu}dx^\mu$    I have some online noter at http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/torsion_review.pdf

Comment: @tparker you may also want to see Ivo Terek’s answer to [A doubt on Tensors: Can they be 1-form valued?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3836718/568204) on MSE. You’ll see that, as mentioned here, the algebraic Bianchi identity is simply a manifestation ‘derivative of zero is zero’ due to lack of torsion, (which can be equivalently described as the covariant exterior derivative of the identity mapping $TM\to TM$). In fact, even if torsion is non-zero, but we merely have that $d_{\nabla}\tau=0$ (i.e the torsion 2-form is covariantly-closed), then we still have the algebraic Bianchi identity.